# How to replace ' for " using gsub in R

Tags: r, replace, gsub

I have a json format in a txt, but I have a problem, the text is like that:

```
content <- {'response': {'page': 1, 'size': None, 'count': 120, 'totalPages': 2,...
```

So it comes to an error. I would like to replace this text for this other one:

```
content <- {"response": {"page": 1, "size": None, "count": 120, "totalPages": 2,...
```

and I'm trying it with the `gsub` function, but I'm having this problem:

```
content2 <- gsub("'", '"', content)
{\"response\": {\"page\": 1, \"size\": None, \"count\": 120, \"totalPages\": 2,...
```

How can I solve that?

Thanks.

Comment: Does gsub("\\'", '\\"', content) work instead? If not, could you make a small piece of the data copy-pasteable for us to work on?

Comment: Not really, still the same result.

Comment: Also, maybe just `gsub("\'", '\"', content)`? But I'm just guessing.